# how to change orientation of multipolygon in shapely

Tags: python, shapely

In Shapely lib, there exists a handy function to set the orientation of polygon. Assuming `sz` is regular shapely `Polygon`:

```
sz = shapely.geometry.polygon.orient(sz, sign=1.0)
```

If instead sz is a `Multipolygon`, then above fails. Since it is iterable, I also tried the following:

```
# Fails:    
for ii in range(len(sz)):
    sz[ii] = shapely.geometry.polygon.orient(sz[ii], sign=1.0)
```

But multipolygons do not support item assignment. A solution is to grab all of the polygons, change the orientation, and then create a new `Multipolygon`:

```
# Works, but I hope for something better:
szl = []
for s in sz:
   szl.append(shapely.geometry.polygon.orient(s, sign=1.0))
sz = shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon(szl)
```

This is alot of overhead in execution and memory, and is not as easy to understand as the solution for single polygon. Is there a nicer solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension. Also, to make it a bit less cumbersome to read, you could import the function you want directly:

```py
from shapely.geometry.polygon import orient
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon

sz = MultiPolygon([orient(s, sign=1.0) for s in sz])
```

This is an admittedly ugly solution, but it's likely going to be a bit faster and more readable.

Comment: thanks. This is nicer than what I have so upvote.... but cant accept this as an answer, for the reason you mentioned in the last sentence of your answer.